# localStorage keeps adding '0'. (jScript & HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

Well, my code have been working fine and I'm simply trying to make a simple game, until I added this (due to that I wanted to learn how to save the info to the users local storage):

```
if(localStorage.getItem('money'))
{
    var Money = localStorage.getItem('money');
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="EXISTS";
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('money', 0);
    var Money = localStorage.getItem('money');
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="DOES NOT EXIST";
}
```

My full code looks like this:

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body><span id='test'></span>
Generated something: <span id='money'>0$</span> (money per click: <span id='MPC'>1$</span>)
<br />
Upgrade 1 upgrades: <span id='u1Us'>0</span> (production rate: <span id='u1Pr'>0</span>)
<br />
<span id='updates'></span>
<br />
<button onClick='mButton()'>Generate something.</button>
<br /><br />
<b>Upgrades:</b>

<br /><br />Generator upgrades:<br />
<button onClick='buyU1()'>Buy upgrade 1. ($30)</button>
<br /><br />Self-generated upgrades:<br />
<button onClick='buySG1()'>Buy Self-Generated Upgrade 1 ($500)</button>
</body>
<script>
if(localStorage.getItem('money'))
{
    var Money = localStorage.getItem('money');
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="EXISTS";
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('money', 0);
    var Money = localStorage.getItem('money');
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="DOES NOT EXIST";
}

var U1Amount = 0;
var cMoney = 1;

function mButton()
{
    Money += cMoney;
    document.getElementById('money').innerHTML=Money + "$";
}
function buyU1()
{
    if(Money < 30)
        {
            document.getElementById('updates').innerHTML="You do not have enough money.";
            resetUpdates();
        } else {
            Money -= 30;
            U1Amount += 1;
            document.getElementById('u1Us').innerHTML=U1Amount;
            document.getElementById('money').innerHTML=Money + "$";
            document.getElementById('updates').innerHTML="You have successfully bought Upgrade 1";
            var calcU1Amount = U1Amount * 5;
            document.getElementById('u1Pr').innerHTML=calcU1Amount;
            resetUpdates();
        }
}
var interval = setInterval(gMoneyU1, 1000);
function gMoneyU1()
{
    var calc = 5 * U1Amount;
    Money += calc;
    document.getElementById('money').innerHTML=Money + "$";
}
function buySG1()
{
    if(Money < 500)
        {
            document.getElementById('updates').innerHTML="You do not have enough money.";
            resetUpdates();
        } else {
            Money -= 500;
            cMoney += 1;
            document.getElementById('MPC').innerHTML=cMoney + "$";
            document.getElementById('money').innerHTML=Money;
        }
}
function resetUpdates()
{
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('updates').innerHTML="";}, 10000);
}
</script>
```

I'm going to add the localStorage to all info that I want to save, but I'm having problems with the first one so yer.
What my code WITH my save-the-persons-info outputs is: http://puu.sh/6iONl.png (and it keeps on in all eternally)

It keeps adding '0' for some reason and I can't figure out why. I'd really appreciate help.
Thanks in advance.

Sorry if my code is messy, I'm still learning, hence why asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

The only time that you ever set to localStorage is when you call `localStorage.setItem('money', 0);`.

You probably want to change that to setting the real value of the money variable.

Comment: 0 is the real value of the money variable if it hasn't been set before.

Comment: Well, you are never updating it to another value when it changes.

Comment: I assume that part will be added when the current bug doesn't plague the code. It would hardly be benefical to interact more with localStorage if not even the first value retrieved from it works the way it should. Either way, i am trying to say that the fact that 0 is set to localStorage is not the OP's problem.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what the expected behavior and logic is supposed to be. So, I do agree that there is something missing here.  But if the only time that localStorage is set, it is set to 0, then it should not be surprising that the only value it returns is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage stores everything as a string, so you'll want to call `parseInt()` on whatever you get back from local storage. Then, you should be able to properly add two ints together, rather than concatenating two strings together.

Answer (score 0):

The values in localStorage are all strings. When you do:

```
localStorage.setItem('x', 0);
var x = localStorage.getItem('x'); // x === '0'
x = x + 1; // x = '01';
```

the thing you set in local storage will be the value you gave converted to a string. You should parseInt (or convert it some other way back to a number) when you retrieve it from localStorage to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement will always return false so you'll never get to the "if true" part of your if statement. This is because the local storage value will either be null if not set, or a string value ("0") on most browsers if set, or an integer on some browsers if set. (Most browsers will only maintain strings for local storage, although the HTML5 specs do allow for other values.)

So first, of you would need to change the if part to something like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('money') != null)
```

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve logic-wise but as mentioned, your other issue is that you're only setting the value to 0 and then reading the value right after (which would be zero still.) This is why you're getting zeros.